# which are Linux specific Hadoop internals?

Tags: linux, hadoop, cygwin, internals

I am trying to learn why hadoop requires cygwin in windows apart from running shell script. I know there are POSIX specific implementations in various hadoop parts, i just wanted to know exactly which parts of hadoop are Linux specific?

Thanks

Comment: I'd suppose the native libs in `lib/native`, run scripts and configs.

Answer (score 2):

Some Hadoop internals require details information or operations about the system that are not provided by Java.

For it is IIRC not possible to change the owner of a file in Java 6.

However, Hadoop needs this type of operation. In these cases, Hadoop executes the Unix commands in a separate process. The utility class [Shell](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/src/core/org/apache/hadoop/util/Shell.java) contains a lot of these sub process calls.

The list includes

- *ulimit*
- *chmod*
- *whoami*
- *ls*
- and others

For similar reasons, the class [ProcessTree](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/src/core/org/apache/hadoop/util/ProcessTree.java) uses *setsid* and *kill*.

As Hadoop uses the applications, they have to be available on the parent system. Cygwin provides this.

[Edit:]
Actually, the native code in lib/native is optional. It is only used (for performance reasons) if matching library versions are there.

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop uses shell scripts to start and stop master and slave processes, among other things.  It also requires openssh (passwordless).  Installing cygwin is the simplest way to address this.